# nano : where are "morespace" and "smooth" settings gone

Tags: macos, homebrew, nano

In the transition from Cygwin+Windows to MacOS Monterey, I also tried to port my configuration of the nano editor. On the Mac, I had to use Homebrew (`brew install nano`) to get a decent `nano`, because the default `nano` is just a symlink to `pico`.

Homebrew works fine and I now have GNU nano 7.2, a newer version than I had available on Cygwin. However, in my .nanorc, the settings `morespace` and `smooth` are not recognized anymore (Error message: *Unknown option: ....*).

Are these options not available anymore, or have they been replaced by a different option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were indeed removed (see the [ChangeLog](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/ChangeLog)):

> ### Changes between v5.6.1 and v5.7:
>
> ```
>   options: retire the obsolete 'smooth', 'morespace', and 'nopauses'
> ```

The two options are now obsolete since they are the default behavior. Here is from a man page (for an older version):

> ```
> −O, −−morespace
>
> Obsolete and ignored option, since the line below the title bar is
> included into the editing space by default. If you prefer to keep this
> line blank, use −e or −−emptyline.
>
> −S, −−smooth
>
> Obsolete and ignored option, since smooth scrolling has become the
> default. If you prefer the chunk-by-chunk scrolling behavior, use −j
> or −−jumpyscrolling.
> ```